# Django error "Page not found " with "no year specified" in detailed view

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I trying to make an app with *Kenneth Love: Getting Started with Django, a crash course  from PyCon 2014*  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KZHXjGP71kQ. And I have an error, which in title of this question.
App created on django 1.7.4, postgresql 9.4, python 3.4 .

Comment: Can you show us the code you wrote please? Where exacly did it throw the error?

Comment: Code http://pastebin.com/DFr4kY6L
I have an error when trying to get detailed view

Comment: Which line did it throw it to you?

Comment: localhost.loc/talks/lists/ - working,  and I see the list, а localhost.loc/talks/lists/onerecord - not working, I think it something with slugs in views.py but I dont know how to fix it

Comment: I understand, but what we're trying to get is which line of the code is not working as it should. This way we can inspect that line specifically, and understand if your mistake is logical or syntax-related, and then help you fix it.

Comment: I fixed it.  The right way  is `generic.DetailView` instead  `generic.DateDetailView`.
Anyway thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The right way is `generic.DetailView` instead `generic.DateDetailView`